# How can I disable the phpMyAdmin login page?

Tags: php, sql, mysql, html, security

I use phpmyadmin, and when entering this adress:

```
 www.mydomain.com/phpmyadmin
```

a login page appears.

Is there any way of disabling it, so it doesn't appear/exist?

Thanks

Comment: There are better DBA tools out there. I'm in love with Navicat

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yep, you can: set your password in the config file. BUT if you are using this on your domain then I'd strongly recommend you take it off your site altogether!

Use a client to access your database - like mysql workbench or mysql yog or any of the numerous ones out there.

If you MUST use phpmyadmin then why not install it on your local machine and add the details to the config there? It is much safer.

Comment: How do I do the later one. Install it on my local computer and configure it there? How do you mean, what is this method called? Links please...

Comment: You can use XAMPP : http://sourceforge.net/projects/xampp/
Then edit the config file and configure host/login/database... be aware that some databases can't be access from an other domain (ie, a database at mydomain.com can only be access from a script in the same domain). Often true for free "host", false if you are paying.

Comment: @Camran: You will need to set up a local server with phpMyAdmin on it. Just search for WAMP / LAMP on Google, there are tons of free servers that come pre-installed with phpMyAdmin.

Answer (score 55):

You can disable phpMyAdmin by disabling the module configuration.

```
sudo a2disconf phpmyadmin.conf
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

Enable it with

```
sudo a2enconf phpmyadmin.conf
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

Comment: This was what I was looking for, couldn't find any reference to phpmyadmin in my apache sites config. This explains that, because it's a module.

Answer (score 23):

In your config.inc.php file change:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type']    = 'config';
```

and add

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user']         = 'root';  
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password']     = 'password';
```

Comment: $cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type']    = 'config';   helped me. tnx

Comment: If somebody struggles to locate a config file on Ubuntu it's `/etc/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php`

Comment: And the location of config file on windows wamp server: `/wamp/apps/phpmyadminx.x.x/config.inc.php`

Answer (score 13):

In centos, locate the file in directory `/etc/httpd/conf.d/phpmyadmin.conf/` and uncomment these lines to only give access on the local system to phpmyadmin, and leave the users from outside with no access to phpmyadmin

```
<Directory "/usr/share/phpmyadmin">
  Order Deny,Allow
  Deny from all
  Allow from 127.0.0.1
</Directory>
```

Hope this be helpfull

Comment: It's a web application, unless you are using curl this is not going to work without a browser.  Why not a local subnet. Better still leave it like this and open it on demand by reconfiguring on the fly.

Answer (score 3):

**Preventing remote login doesn’t stop access to phpmyadmin** if you have not stopped it in /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf

To turn the access to phpmyadmin OFF **in ubuntu 14.04 with apache** web server, **edit /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf**

Search for or if you set the Alias /phpmyadmin /usr/share/phpmyadmin in the same file.

**Add or Edit following lines**: Order Deny, Allow Deny from all

**Restart apache2** with sudo service apache2 restart

To turn the access to phpmyadmin ON temporarily, first find out your ip address. Search Google, what is my ip address. Then edit vi /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf file. Add this line to the above mentioned Directory tag: Allow from

Restart the apache2 with sudo service apache2 restart

Answer (score 2):

Just an idea. If someone must have PhpMyAdmin installed, it is also possible to "hide it" under another url.

In case of a Debian/Apache web server find the `apache.conf` in the phpmyadmin directory and change:

`Alias /phpmyadmin /usr/share/phpmyadmin`
to
`Alias /yourspecialurl /usr/share/phpmyadmin`

Don't forget to restart Apache with the new config...

Comment: combining this with creating a disable/enable script with the commands from Litehouse's answer is probably the most secure way to use phpmyadmin from any device while preserving a reasonable security!

Answer (score 1):

One thing you may want to do is just use a `.htaccess` file to redirect that URL somewhere to basically restrict the ability to get to that URL.

To do this, just create a `.htaccess` file at the root directory of your domain and put this in it:

```
Redirect 301 /phpmyadmin http://www.mydomain.com/
```

Then whenever you need to access phpmyadmin, you would just have to comment out that line temporarily while you do your work.

Comment: That is creating another problem instead of giving a solution.

Comment: I disagree that it causes a problem. It may not behave as they would like, but it does solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

To disable PhpMyAdmin page need to edit an configuration file as below

vi /opt/lampp/etc/extra/httpd-xampp.conf around 64th line edit:

```
Deny from all

    TO 

Deny from none
```

> ```
>   Order deny,allow
>   Deny from all  /*none*/
>   Allow from ::1 127.0.0.0/8 \
>   fc00::/7 10.0.0.0/8 172.16.0.0/12 192.168.0.0/16 \
>   fe80::/10 169.254.0.0/16
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You can disable phpMyAdmin by disabling the module configuration. (UPDATED)

```
sudo a2disconf phpmyadmin.conf
sudo systemctl restart apache2
```

Enable it with

```
sudo a2enconf phpmyadmin.conf
sudo systemctl restart apache2
```

Answer (score -7):

You can remove it completely with this command:

```
sudo apt-get purge phpmyadmin
```

Comment: this will remove the phpmyadmin too

Comment: "You are technically correct - the best kind of correct"

Comment: Don't do this. You'll remove the whole instance of phpmyadmin not just the login page.